# Fever Dream Out of Something Meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of the second part of the sentence below?

> This underground bomb shelter, built by Tito, seemed as large and as
>   crazy as a small country, not to mention a fever dream out of Dr.
>   Strangelove.

Does it mean the place reminded the author of Dr.Strangelove?

Comment: If he mentioned *Dr. Strangelove* he must have been reminded of it in some sense. Why don't you ask what a fever dream is, since that appears to be your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *fever dream* is an unusually vivid or realistic (and possibly scary) dream, associated with having a fever. Dr Strangelove is an allusion to an old movie, called *Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb*, which was a dark comedy about the accidental outbreak of nuclear war.

Taken together, the bomb shelter is vivid, as in loud and colourful like a marketplace, with a hint of insanity or unexpected events that could be humorous.

Answer (score 1):

By way of supplementing Roaring Fish's answer, it may be relevant to note that in the "War Room" scene near the end of [*Dr. Strangelove*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057012/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu), there is a lengthy discussion of the need for government officials to have access to a maximum-grade bomb shelter capable of withstanding an all-out nuclear attack.

As Dr. Strangelove describes it—to the increasing fascination of General Buck Turgidson—the shelter would be designed to accommodate the most important officials of the U.S. government, including (of course) everyone in the War Room. But owing to the probable annihilation of all humanity outside the shelter and to the need to remain in the shelter for a century or more while the toxicity of the nuclear fallout slowly dissipates, Strangelove says, it would be necessary to include ten women for every man in the shelter, to maximize recovery of the species:

> **General "Buck" Turgidson:** Doctor, you mentioned the ratio of ten women to each man. Now, wouldn't that necessitate the abandonment of the so-called monogamous sexual relationship, I mean, as far as men were concerned?
>
> **Dr. Strangelove:** Regrettably, yes. But it is, you know, a sacrifice required for the future of the human race. I hasten to add that since each man will be required to do prodigious... service along these lines, the women will have to be selected for their sexual characteristics which will have to be of a highly stimulating nature.

Hence the reference to *Dr. Strangelove* in connection with bomb shelters as fever dreams.